# Codeigniter confilcting sessions behind proxy

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

We have a web applications that have just gone live. As this is used on several corporate networks, a peculiar issue has come up.

Users are able to login into the system but users that are behind corporate networks intermittently get logged in/view other users profiles as their own. Esentially the sessions are colliding.

These are the current settings on the server :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 72000;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

We are on amazon behind a load balancer on a LAMP stack.

We're really pulling our hair on this one, any pointers are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to try asking on http://serverfault.com/ and include details on what the topology is (proxies, etc) on both sides. This sounds like an issue on the network layer and not a programmatic issue. A quick google search brought up http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/04/08/support-for-session-stickiness-in-elastic-load-balancing/ which talks about sticky sessions. Basically, if you're using a load balancer with multiple servers behind it, there has to be a mechanism to "stick" the session to the server that originated the session.

Comment: The issue is happening across at least 4 such types of networks, so I would rule out this at this point. Also sticky session comes into play so the same users stick to the same server instance on amazon. Appriciate your taking the time, but, i think its something on the application and session handling thats causing this.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense that it were happening across multiple networks if the sessions aren't sticky; there isn't anything telling the balancer which server to send the request to. So user 1 starts a session on server 1; user 2 starts a session on server 2; user 1's next request goes to server 2 and gets user 2's session. If you haven't made any other modifications to codeigniters sessions, codeigniter is NOT the problem otherwise this issue would pop up for everyone that uses CI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve it for you, but I have had similar problems with two clients who were behind a proxy that was limiting the size of HTTP headers. This wouldn't normally be a problem however there is a bug in Codeigniters Session handler, it writes a new `cookies:` entry for each session variable, rather than doing them all in one go. This causes the HTTP headers to become bloated and can cause problems on some networks if your setting a lot of session variables.

My advice would be to download `Live HTTP Headers` for Firefox and inspect the headers for your site on pages utilizing the session. If you find multiple entries for `cookies:` , it could be causing your problems.

To solve it, I would recommend using your own Session Library. Give [Dariusz Debowczyk's Session Class](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Dariusz-Debowczyk%27s-Session-Class) a try and see what happens. It fixed it for me.

The other alternative would be to contact the network administrator to check what kind of proxy they are using (some older versions of squid proxy gave me problems with codeigniters session) and if they are placing restrictions on the size of HTTP headers.